# read_csv leading to R Session Abort

Tags: r

I am encountering this problem where I try to import csv files from a folder and using bind_cols function, but it keeps making my R session to abort. I am not sure what might be the cause of this. Below are my codes.

```
alldataset<- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Documents/folder1",
                        pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE ) %>%
lapply(read_csv) %>%
bind_cols
```

Comment: @jared_mamrot - that might be true, but aborting the whole session for a syntax error seems like a bug somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that it is a typo/syntax error. `list.files` returns a list of files which is the first argument to `lapply`. `read_csv` is applied to each file. You could try shorter version with `list.files(...) %>% map_dfc(read_csv)` but session abort is most likely because of big files that you are trying to read and combine. Try `vroom` as suggested by @jared_mamrot .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the R Session is running out of memory.

One idea - instead of `bind_cols`, maybe `bind_rows` is the desired output?

```
dim(iris)
150   5
    
dim(bind_rows(iris, iris))
300   5

dim(bind_cols(iris, iris))
150  10
```